# bcdedit doesn't change the boot entry with a valid path

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, grub, uefi

I installed a W10 / Ubuntu dualboot with uefi on my laptop.

But when I turn on my PC, there is no grub and it automatically boot on windows 10.

When I press the Boot option, then manually select the good efi file (the ubuntu one)

[image]

It works and I have my grub (with ubuntu + windows)

So I tried to change the boot entry with bcdedit like that (in a windows cmd):

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

But I doesn't change anything, and the computer still boot automatically on windows 10.

How can I boot on my shimx64.efi when I turn on my computer ?

Comment: You have to use GRUB to boot to Ubuntu not the Windows Bootloader which bcdedit would be modifying

Comment: @Ramhound I already tried to repair the Grub with boot-repair, wich is suppose to update the Grub Menu, but I still have to manually select shimx64.efi to access it

Comment: @Ramhound, the `bcdedit` tool can modify EFI NVRAM variables on EFI-based computers, and the command specified in the question *should* have worked to do this. It requires some tweaks to the command in some command prompt tools, though, but I don't recall the details.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the third-party [EasyUEFI;](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) it's got a simpler user interface and bypasses some problems that `bcdedit` has.

If that fails, then you likely have a defective EFI. There are several options at this point, in order of preference:

1. Some EFIs require setting a password or explicitly whitelisting binaries before they can be launched. Acer, in particular, is notorious for this. See [this AskUbuntu question and answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot) for information on how to work around this problem.
2. A firmware upgrade (check your manufacturer's Web site) *may* help, but that's a long shot -- and an upgrade may remove the Ubuntu options, which would necessitate re-creating them.
3. If it's still possible, returning the computer for a refund would be my next suggestion. Manufacturers have been far too slow to fix this type of problem. Most have done so, but if you've got a new computer with this bug, there's no excuse at this point. If you return the computer, be sure to write to the manufacturer to tell them why you returned it.
4. A near-final last resort option is to rename the Windows boot loader file (`EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` on the [EFI System Partition [ESP]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition)) to something else and put GRUB (`grubx64.efi`; or Shim [`shimx64.efi`], if you want to boot with Secure Boot active) in its place, then reconfigure GRUB to boot Windows with the new Windows boot loader name. The [Boot Repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) has an option to do this on its "Advanced" menu. You can do something similar with my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) with its `mvrefind` command.
5. The absolute last-ditch possibility is to re-install both Windows and Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode rather than in EFI mode. (You might be able to get by with converting the disk from GPT to MBR and re-installing both OSes' boot loaders, but this process is tedious and can easily end up leading to disaster, so I'd recommend it only if you're an expert.)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu first, this might be normal behavior.

As the comment says, you must use grub.

https://www.lifewire.com/fix-uefi-bootloader-issues-when-dual-booting-2200655

This article may be helpful, it is for uefi system and changes the "boot order"  so that Grub will appear.

Comment: I tried to change the bootorder with efibootmgr but I didn't change anything, and the 2nd solution is what I'm actually doing

Comment: If its a fresh installation, I recommend to reinstall Ubuntu and choose "next to Windows"..

Comment: That's what I did, I first installed Windows via the uefi file then Ubuntu "next to Windows" @johnnyrevival

Comment: Via the uefi file? You mean you booted in uefi mode with the installation media? It should have worked then. Sometimes, if it fails, reinstallation of ubuntu should work.

Comment: Yes in uefi mode, and I tried to reinstall it multiple time already @johnyrevival

Answer (score 0):

(This is meant as a comment on Rod Smith's answer, unfortunately I don't have enough karma.)

My (HP) laptop tries booting `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` first regardless of EFI NVRAM settings, renaming that file worked flawlessly for me.

Don't forget to edit the chainloader line in your `grub.cfg` to point to the renamed Windows EFI. Also Windows will sometimes "fix" your boot partition after updating so you'll have to rename it again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer by [Rod Smith](https://superuser.com/a/1189995/1501178), it helped me solve my problem with the introduction to the software [EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html). I'll be providing my story and hoping it might help someone.

I was changing the bootloader using the `bcdedit` command, but it didn't work out. Looking at the software [EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html), I could see the Fedora bootloader along with the Windows ones (2 windows bootloaders were seen - 2nd one was *probably* used by Grub for booting to Windows), but in the cmd `bcdedit` was showing only one entry, which was getting changed, as could be seen from the EasyUEFI - but the change was happening in the lowest priority ordered Windows Boot loader, which is why it didn't work in the 1st place - [Image showing bootloader order using EasyUEFI vs CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58YPp.png).

But, then there was another problem that even after changing the bootloader priority to Fedora being the top (grub bootloader), after reboot (even with Secure Boot turned off), Windows got boot up! And in the EasyUEFI panel, I could see somehow the Windows Bootloader has come to the top.

The problem got resolved by changing that particular Windows BootLoader path to the Grub bootloader - which is what we usually do by using the command
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path <path_to_the_bootloader>`, but here it was affecting the lowest priority Windows Bootloader previously.